# Как получить доступ к стандартным view элементам android.app.TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, datetimepicker

В моём проекте используется стандартный TimePickerDialog из пакета android.app.TimePickerDialog:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, hour, minute, true)

        //интерфейсы пустые потому что они нужны только для замены текста кнопок
        timePickerDialog.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK"){ p1, p2 -> }
        timePickerDialog.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Закрыть"){ p1, p2 -> }

        return timePickerDialog
    }
```

Мне нужно убрать возможность переключения в режим `spinner`, а также перекрасить часть компонентов диалога.

Используя LayoutInspector AndroidStudio я нашел id нужного мне View:

[image: Изображение искомого View элемента]
Далее переопределяю функцию `onCreate` для своего TimePicker:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view.findViewById<AppCompatImageButton>(android.R.id.toggle_mode).visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Однако в R классе android этого id нет.
Подскажите как получить доступ к view класса android.app.TimePickerDialog?

Comment: Скорее всего это приватный `id` из `com.android.internal.R`. Доступа к нему без костылей нет и никакой гарантии его существования на всех версиях системы и устройств. Думаю надёжнее будет собрать кастомный диалог из таких-же вью-компонентов.

Comment: на то он и стандартный, чтобы его "украшатели" не смогли изменить